# What does "under inclusion" mean in: $R$ is Noetherian ring $\iff$ Every nonempty set of ideals of $R$ contains a maximal element under inclusion.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

$R$ is Noetherian ring $\iff$ Every nonempty set of ideals of $R$ contains a maximal element under inclusion.

What does the phrase "maximal element $\textbf{under inclusion}$" mean? I am having a hard time understanding the context of "under inclusion".

For e.g. assume that we are given any increasing chain of ideals $I_1\subset I_2\subset \cdots$. Since, every set (say $\mathcal{S}$) of ideals of $R$ contains a maximal element under inclusion, meaning that if $\mathcal{S}=\{I_1\}$, then there exist maximal ideal $M$ which satisfy $I_1 \hookrightarrow M$. Similarly, if $\mathcal{S}=\{I_1,I_2\}$, then there exist maximal ideal $M$ which satisfy $I_1 \hookrightarrow M$ and $I_2 \hookrightarrow M$. From here, it is easy to prove that $R$ is Noetherian.

Conversely, Assume that $R$ is Noetherian ring. Let $\mathcal{S}$ be any non-empty set of ideals of $R$ with no
maximal element. Since, $\mathcal{S} \neq \emptyset$, let $I_1$ be in $\mathcal{S}$.
Now, I have seen in some of the references that "Because $I_1$ is not maximal, we can choose $I_2$ in $\mathcal{S}$ with $I_1 \subset I_2$ and $I_1 \neq I_2$."

Doubt: Why does there exist such $I_2$ in the above statement. (Or you can give some other explanation. I guess this is where "under inclusion" comes to picture.)

Comment: See e.g. the following [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509976/does-there-exist-a-nonempty-s-%e2%8a%86-pn-with-no-maximal-elements) : it is the maximal element in a *chain* of inclusions.

Comment: See the [Poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Examples) formed by the set of subsets of a given set (its power set) ordered by inclusion.

Comment: If there did not exist such an $I_2$, then $I_1$ would be maximal in $\mathcal{S}$ with respect to subset inclusion, thus contradicting the supposistion.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can we say, equivalently, that If $R$ is Noetherian ring and if the set $\mathcal{S}$ contains ideals $I_1,I_2,I_3,\cdots$  under inclusion (that is to say that $I_1 \subset I_2 \subset I_3\subset \cdots$) then we have to prove that the maximal element exist for this inclusion? (I guess the point is that maximal element makes sense under some "orderedness" which "inclusion" provides here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the phrase "maximal element under inclusion" mean?

The phrase "maximal element" has no meaning unless some partial order is indicated.

That's what "under inclusion" means: the partial order is the set containment relation $\subseteq$.

> Now, I have seen in some of the references that "Because $I_1$ is not maximal, we can choose $I_2$ in $\mathcal{S}$ with $I_1 \subset I_2$ and $I_1 \neq I_2$." [...] Doubt: Why does there exist such $I_2$ in the above statement.

Because that is what "not maximal" means.  If no such $I_2$ existed, $I_1$ *would* be maximal. I would encourage you to look at the definition of "maximal" and contemplate its negation, and you will understand.